# Libgdx distance field font support on iOS

Tags: java, ios, libgdx, shader

Using distance field fonts like explained in the Libgdx wiki: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Distance-field-fonts
Gives good results on android. I'm using the example shader provided.

But when I run the same program on iOS the text is filled up with white everywhere (see image below).
Is distance field not supported by iOS or do I need to add/change something else to get it to work?

[image: distance field problem]

shader code font.vert:

```
uniform mat4 u_projTrans;

attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;
attribute vec4 a_color;

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main() {
    gl_Position = u_projTrans * a_position;
    v_texCoord = a_texCoord0;
    v_color = a_color;
}
```

font.frag:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
    precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform sampler2D u_texture;

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

const float smoothing = 1.0/16.0;

void main() {
    float distance = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord).a;
    float alpha = smoothstep(0.5 - smoothing, 0.5 + smoothing, distance);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(v_color.rgb, alpha);
}
```

Loading the fonts like this:

```
BitmapFont bf = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/mont-b.fnt"));
bf.getRegion().getTexture().setFilter(TextureFilter.MipMapLinearNearest, TextureFilter.Linear);
```

and the shader:

```
fontShader = new ShaderProgram(Gdx.files.internal("shader/font.vert"),     Gdx.files.internal("shader/font.frag"));
```

Comment: This looks like an error in the shader causing it not to compile. Sometimes a shader with errors will compile completely fine on certain devices because they are more lenient about the syntax than described in the OpenGL ES 2.0 spec.  Please share your vertex and fragment shader code.

Comment: I am using the exact same code as provided on the wiki: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Distance-field-fonts#rendering-with-a-shader

Comment: Hmm, I don't see any problems with it. After you instantiate the ShaderProgram, call `Gdx.app.log("dist field shader", shaderProgram.getLog());` so you can see if it really is the shader. It might also be the way you are loading the Texture. Can you show your texture loading code?

Comment: I'm unable to test at this time, but I did add the font loading (and shader loading) code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue might be that you don't have mip mapping enabled on your font texture, because you simply used the simple BitmapFont constructor with no TextureRegion argument, so it loads the Texture with the assumption of no mip maps.

You must create a Texture that supports mip maps like this, as shown on the libgdx wiki:

```
Texture texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("yourFont.png"), true); //true to enable mip maps
texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.MipMapLinearNearest, TextureFilter.Linear);
```

Then you can load your BitmapFont using the mip map Texture, so the BitmapFont won't create its own Texture with no mip maps:

```
BitmapFont bf = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("fonts/mont-b.fnt"), new TextureRegion(texture));
```

Comment: This sounds quite plausible. I will check it in a few hours and let you know if it works!

Comment: Doesn't explain why it worked on Android though...that's why I initially thought the shader was the problem. But maybe there are some Android GPU's that automatically downgrade a mip map filter to the non-mip map version if a texture doesn't have mip mapping.

Comment: Or it could be that I do not downsize them on my android phone which has a much higher resolution than the ipad 2 I use for iOS testing. I'm not 100% sure about this but this could make the difference.

Comment: The min mapping sypport was indeed the problem, thanks a bunch!

Comment: That would explain it. It was probably reading the highest (only) mip level that was in the texture because of the device's high resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. However, iOS uses pre-multiplied alpha for all images by default. So, the image that you are using is converted to pre-multiplied alpha format and not the same that you supplied.

Not sure where exactly, but you need to disable pre-multiplied alpha for the image and the "boxes" will be gone.

And no, your problem is not related to mipmapping.